# cabal: Ignoring trailing fields after sections:

Tags: hackage

I try to upload a package to hackage. I have included a `README.md` and a `ChangeLog.md` file and mentioned them in the `.cabal` file:

```
extra-source-files:
    README.md
    ChangeLog.md
```

but receive, when uploading the `dist` file to hackage, a cryptic error message:

```
Ignoring trailing fields after sections: "extra-source-files".
```

On the web I found some hints to consider the `cabal.cabal` file as en example, but the format used there did not satisfy the checks of hackage.

It would be highly desirable, that `cabal sdist` does apply the same strict testing than hackage upload - and preferably with error message which not only tell what is wrong from the programmer perspective but hint to a corrective action; for example: where should the information in the "trailing fields" go.